# Python3 to clojure IPC

Tags: clojure, python-3.x, ipc, rpc

I have a strange request. We're in a position where we need to run a clojure based service in between our python3.3 worker and a database. I'm looking into different ways to interface between python and clojure for this reason. I looked at Thrift, but unfortunately it's doesn't have python3 support yet. 0mq also looked interesting but I'm worried about the req/req pattern blocking the python3 threads (there will be multiple threads on multiple processes needing to use this proxy service).

Are there any other existing libraries in existence that could help me out here? At the end of the day I could write my own service from scratch using aleph and raw sockets, but I feel like that would be re-inventing the wheel too much.

Comment: meet in the middle - https://github.com/halgari/clojure-py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure means JVM. Most languages running on the JVM allow "calling Java" and be "called by Java" which basically means anything else on the JVM. I've never done it, but you can probably call Clojure from Jython. Now Jython doesn't support the Python 3 language, but it does support Pyro.

It's a bit far-fetched but you could try:

```
                                     JVM
     Python-VM             Jython           Clojure
( Your app -> Pyro ) --> ( Pyro -> Proxy -> Your app )
```

Arguments of the RMI must probably be translated to Java primitives & Java strings. It might also require some ClassLoader-Voodoo.

Comment: Since the only reason I had clojure in there in the first place was because the python driver for the database doesn't support python3 yet, and Pyro is python2/3 compatible, I could drop clojure and just stick a python2.7 proxy in there instead. Marking this as the accepted answer for showing me pyro :)

Answer (score 2):

I am using ZeroMQ in Python in production quite happily so far; there is Clojure support as well, which I have not really used yet -- it requires native libraries which can be a bit inconvenient.  I am going with your ZeroMQ reference even though it's not a full RPC mechanism because often RPC problems can be broken down fairly simply as operations on one or more message queues.

Meanwhile, there is also [clojure-py](https://github.com/halgari/clojure-py), which would allow you to have your Python and eat your Clojure too.  It is still quite young and not without rough edges but most of the core functionality is in place.

Finally, there is always XML-RPC for which both [Clojure](https://github.com/brehaut/necessary-evil) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) have libraries, if you just want something simple to glue your Python and Clojure together.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to XML-RPC! I love the name for the clojure implementation. Unfortunately it's not a constant connection, which is another requirement (forgot to mention it, sorry =/).